# What's the procedure for setting up SalesForce to receive traffic from a custom URL?

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites, custom-domain, custom-url

I'm a DNS admin that needs to work with a marketing team to get traffic from a custom domain/URL directed into our Salesforce account.

That is, traffic from `custom.com` should end up at `ourcompany.force.com/custom`.

The final page can display the custom domain OR the force.com domain; it doesn't really matter in this case.  Keeping the custom domain would be cool though.

I'm trying to figure out:

1. What do I need to set up in DNS for Salesforce to confirm ownership of the custom domain?
2. What needs to be done in our Salesforce account to route the traffic from the custom domain to the correct location?

On my end, I can purchase the custom domain/URL and configure DNS to route the traffic where ever it needs to be sent; CNAMEs would be nice.  I don't have access to our Salesforce account though; I'm working with our SF admins and would like to get them the info they need to set things up on their end.

I've tried once to discuss this with the Salesforce admins but I said "redirect" and that may have pointed the conversation into a dead end as I'm pretty sure a redirect is not what is needed in this situation.  However, I don't know the correct terms to give from their perspective to bridge the gap.

Any assistance that can be provided is appreciated!

Thanks, ~M.

Comment: Are you looking to just have custom.com redirect to ourcompany.force.com/custom, or do you want a full URL mask (e.g. if you're going to be using a custom branded site and you want to hide the fact that your underlying implementation is built on Salesforce)?

Comment: Full URL mask, implemented from DNS; not a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to redirect from custom.com to a Salesforce site... ask the admins to have a look [here!](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm&language=en)

Once you have set up a site you can just have custom.com redirect to the Salesforce site. You'll possible need a dev to set up the Visualforce page for that... ooorrr you could set up a Salesforce Community where you can use templates to set things up, info on that [here!](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_overview.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  Its not the correct one, but it did lead me to what I believe is the right procedure.  In my case, the site is already there, I just needed the procedure to set up the DNS so I can get traffic from custom.com to the site that is already in SF.  [This was the page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_domains.htm&language=en_US) that started to make sense for my situation.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want your SF admins to attempt to [add a Domain](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_mgmt_add.htm&language=en_US). On the `Domain Management -> Domains -> Add Domain` page, they will see the CNAME information you're looking for in the form of a message that looks like:

```
Your domain name is a CNAME record that points to
    [domain].00da0000000xxxxxxx.live.siteforce.com.
As an example, if you are adding www.example.com,
    it must be a CNAME record that points to
    www.example.com.00da0000000xxxxxxx.live.siteforce.com.
```

The `00da0000000xxxxxxx` value is unique to your production SF org. Once you have this value, the DNS Admin/Webmaster (you) will need to add a CNAME entry on your side. In this case, it would look something like the following, assuming you don't want to use a subdomain:

```
www.custom.com.00da0000000xxxxxxx.live.siteforce.com
```

Once you add the CNAME entry on your side, they'll be able to proceed with adding the custom domain (they'll get an error when attempting to save until SF picks up the entry). In my experience, the CNAME entries can take up to an hour to propagate.

Next, your SF admins will need to [add a Custom URL](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_url_add.htm&language=en_US). They'll find this on the `Domain Management -> Custom URLs -> New Custom URL` page, where they'll select the Domain they just created and the Site it will be associated with (this can be an existing Force.com Site or a Community). You'll most likely want to leave the Path as the default of `/`.

Full URL rebranding is only available via SSL, and will only work with a signed certificate. Send your SF admins over to the `Security Controls -> Certificate and Key Management` page and have them [create a CA-Signed Certificate](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_keys_creating.htm) with your domain and company's information. You can then use the generated `.csr` file to purchase a cert from one of the Certificate Authorities. You'll then need your SF admins to upload the signed `.cert` file to activate the Cert/Key pair.

As a final step, your SF admins will have to return to the Domains page and edit the domain they initially created in order to associate the correct Certificate/Key with it. You may also need to have them head back to the Site/Community in question to correct the Custom URLs in the related list on that page - sometimes when associating a Custom URL with a Site, Salesforce doesn't check the `Site Primary Custom URL` box next to your Custom URL! They will also want to check the `Require Secure Connections (HTTPS)` box on the Site/Community, which will force any visitors to your secure URL.

And that's pretty much it, aside from waiting for the DNS entries to propagate. Once they take effect, you should be able to hit your custom URL and be presented with the SF Site/Community Home Page (most likely a VF page).